# Why pipeline based on multithreading in python can improve efficiency

Tags: python, multithreading, queue, pipeline

Although Python supports multiple threads of execution, the `GIL` causes only one of them to make forward progress at a time. However, after I read 《Effective Python》, I implemented pipeline example in this book. The code is below, the entire process is divided into 3 stages, namely download, resize and upload.

```
from threading import Thread
from queue import Queue
import time

# define operation functions for 3 stages: download, resize and upload
def download(item):
    print("downloading {}".format(item))
    time.sleep(2)
    return item
    
def resize(item):
    print("resizing {}".format(item))
    time.sleep(3)
    return item
    
def upload(item):
    print("uploading {}".format(item))
    time.sleep(5)
    return item

# subclass of Thread
class StoppableWorker(Thread):
    def __init__(self, func, in_queue, out_queue):
        super(StoppableWorker, self).__init__()
        self.func = func
        self.in_queue = in_queue
        self.out_queue = out_queue
        
    def run(self):
        for item in self.in_queue:
            result = self.func(item)
            self.out_queue.put(result)

# subclass of Queue
class ClosableQueue(Queue):
    SENTINEL = object()
    
    def close(self):
        self.put(self.SENTINEL)
    
    def __iter__(self):
        while True:
            item = self.get()
            try:
                if item is self.SENTINEL:
                    return
                yield item
            finally:
                self.task_done()

download_queue = ClosableQueue()
resize_queue = ClosableQueue()
upload_queue = ClosableQueue()
output_queue = ClosableQueue()
threads = [StoppableWorker(download, download_queue, resize_queue),
           StoppableWorker(resize, resize_queue, upload_queue),
           StoppableWorker(upload, upload_queue, output_queue)]

for t in threads:
    t.start()

st = time.time()
for i in range(10):
    download_queue.put(i)
download_queue.close()
download_queue.join()
resize_queue.close()
resize_queue.join()
upload_queue.close()
upload_queue.join()
print("It took {}".format(time.time() - st))
print(output_queue.qsize(), 'items finished')
```

According to the output time, I found time spent for N task is `10 + (N-1)*5` seconds (10 = 2(download stage) + 3(resize stage) + 5(upload stage)). It seems that these 3 threads can work at the same time, which is contradicted to the above description that only one of the threads can make forward progress at a time

Comment: Yes, the `GIL` causes only one thread to execute at any one instant in time, but *all* threads can `sleep()` simultaneously. This is why threads are useful for anything that blocks (like network access).

Answer (score 0):

- **Threading in I/O tasks:**

Threading is game-changing because many scripts related to network/data I/O spend the majority of their time waiting for data from a remote source. Because downloads might not be linked (i.e., scraping separate websites), the processor can download from different data sources in parallel and combine the result at the end. For CPU intensive processes, there is little benefit to using the threading module.

- [What Is Threading? Why Might You Want It?](https://timber.io/blog/multiprocessing-vs-multithreading-in-python-what-you-need-to-know/)